# while loop lock subcribing

Tags: ros, multithreading

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,I'm part of an international project team working on robot using ROS.
We are stuck with a problem about multithreading. The code below never exit the loop because of the _current_angle is not changed:

```
  while(ros::ok() && _current_angle <= -1)
  {
    ROS_INFO("[Navigation::Navigation] angle: %g", _current_angle);
    _motor_power_pub.publish(_motor_power_msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
```

You may be agree that it should not change by itself but the _current_angle is modified in a function called back by the subscriber.

The problem, I think, is that during the while loop the function called back from the subscriber is not executed. How should we manage it then ?

> PS : the _current_angle is a class' attribute and the part of the code below is in the constructor of this class.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49964/while-loop-lock-subcribing/) by [Auzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/3747/auzias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My bad, sorry. The problem was that I subscribe to the topic (to change the _current_angle) **after** the constructor. Now it's working . About the code (which is on githug) I cannot post the link due to low karma:
https:// github. com/kissdestinator/FroboMind

---

Originally posted by [Auzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/3747/auzias/) with karma: 26 on 2012-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0